# IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-loadermanager

I am using appcompat support library v22 and creating a ViewPager from MainActivity with three fragments. Following is the code to setup ViewPager which is called from `onCreate()` of MainActivity.

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabAdapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mTabAdapter.addFragment(new CarFragment(), "Cars");
    mTabAdapter.addFragment(new VehiclesRecycleListFragment(), "Vehicles");
    mTabAdapter.addFragment(new BikeFragment(), "Bikes");

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mTabAdapter);
}
```

All three fragments use `LoaderManager` to load data and showing it in RecyclerView. The issue is that one of the fragment (VehiclesRecycleListFragment), `throws "IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to Activity"` in getLoaderManager() randomly after running for a long time (maybe after a few resumes). Since we are catching that exception, the fragment is not crashing but the functionalities are crippled now. Before this point, application is running fine.

We tried to debug into getLoaderManager, and following is the code which throws exception after checking mHost

```
/**
 * Return the LoaderManager for this fragment, creating it if needed.
 */
public LoaderManager getLoaderManager() {
    if (mLoaderManager != null) {
        return mLoaderManager;
    }
    if (mHost == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to Activity");
    }
    mCheckedForLoaderManager = true;
    mLoaderManager = mHost.getLoaderManager(mWho, mLoadersStarted, true);
    return mLoaderManager;
}
```

I am not able to understand is that if a fragment is displaying and running fine inside ViewPager, how come it's not attached to activity.

Please help me to resolve this, let me know if you need more details.

Comment: can you add your `VehiclesRecycleListFragment()` class code in the question?

Comment: Oops..i checked question date after posting comment..Is this issue resolved?